# Запуск фонового процесса Python

Tags: python

Кейс следующий: есть приложение на Python
в main.py вызывается запуск процесса check_radio.py

```
def start_check_radio():
    check_radio_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'check_radio.py')
    for proc in psutil.process_iter(['name']):
        if proc.info['name'] == 'python.exe' and check_radio_path in proc.cmdline():
            proc.kill()
    else:
        subprocess.Popen(['python', check_radio_path], creationflags=subprocess.CREATE_NO_WINDOW)


start_check_radio()

player = FTPMusicPlayer()
player.run()
```

Если запускаю код в PyCharm, всё работает как надо. При закрытии основного окна приложения = check_radio работает в фоне.
Но после компиляции в exe через
`pyinstaller -w --onefile main.py` выполняется только основное приложения без запуска процесса check_radio.py

Подскажите, как быть и куда копать. Спасибо

UPD: Получилось запустить с явным указанием абсолютного пути к python.exe, но это не выход.

Может есть идеи?

Comment: Ваш код запускает файл check_radio.py и после компиляции тоже пытается запустить файл check_radio.py а не какой-то другой и этот файл не собирается в exe т.к. на него нет ссылки в коде

Comment: не совсем понимаю. мне и нужно запускать check_radio

Comment: Тогда check_radio.py должен находиться в той же папке, что и ваш exe файл и на компьютере должен быть установлен python либо скомпилируйте check_radio.py в exe и запускайте exe файл из кода вы также можете использовать pyinstaller --add-data чтобы заархивировать его в основной exe

Comment: я пробовал и добавлять в exe и класть рядом с main.exe
На миллисекунду появляется консоль и сразу же исчезает, не запуская процесс check_radio

Comment: Замените `'python'` на полный путь к исполняемому файлу python.exe и компилируйте с параметром `--add-data "ПУТЬ/К/check_radio.py;."`

Comment: Так заработало, спасибо. Теперь бы без пути к python)

Comment: Компилируете check_radio в exe и запускаете его точно также только без python

Comment: я не могу его положить в main.exe рядом с main.py?

Comment: Скомпилируйте check_radio после, чтобы положить его в main.exe используйте аргумент `--add-data "ПУТЬ/К/check_radio.exe;."` однако лучше будет если вы попытаетесь запихнуть всё в один py файл к примеру с помощью `threading`

Comment: Спасибо. попробую

Comment: Запихнул всё в main.py, но без абсолютного пути не работает

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте не использовать `subprocess` а использовать `threading` к примеру так:
main.py

```py
import check_radio
from threading import Thread

thread = None


def start_check_radio():
    global thread
    thread = Thread(target=check_radio.main)
    thread.start()


def stop_check_radio():
    check_radio.running = False
    if thread:
        thread.join()


start_check_radio()

try:
    player = FTPMusicPlayer()
    player.run()
finally:
    stop_check_radio()
stop_check_radio()
```

check_radio.py

```py
import time

running = True  # Ключ к остановке выполнения


def main():
    # Замени это своим кодом
    while running:
        time.sleep(1)
```